# Command 'flutter' is not executing

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been encountering issues during the installation of Flutter on Windows. I followed the instructions on the website, extracting the files and adding the corresponding PATH, but when attempting to execute any command in CMD or PowerShell, it doesn't work.

Additionally, I tried installing Dart SDK. While I could execute its commands in CMD, installing its VSCode extension consistently resulted in an error message in the corner of the screen: 'The Dart Analysis Server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted. See the output for more information.' This error occurred upon opening VSCode or trying to use any function of the extension.

However, when trying to execute 'flutter doctor' in CMD, the following error is displayed:

```
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.
[Process finished with exit code 1 (0x00000001)]
```

It's worth mentioning that Git is correctly installed. When I try to run any Flutter command as an administrator, CMD closes automatically. In contrast, using PowerShell provides the following error:

```
Error running 'flutter.bat': The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ flutter doctor
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ flutter doctor
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

I've been trying to resolve this error for about a week, experimenting with different solutions from various forums. I've tried installing and uninstalling VSCode, testing different versions of Flutter and Dart SDK, relocating the Flutter folder to different locations, and adding various Git and PowerShell paths. However, nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is for not having git on your OS.
To install it -> https://git-scm.com/downloads

But if you installed Flutter SDK, base on what [Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows) said for windows you shouldn't have any problem.